# Seeking good sources for icons, artwork etc

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry

Has anyone got a good source for icons that can be used in an application?

I'm thinking of things like pushpins, scope sights, house, car, shop, and other small graphics you might overlay on a map or picture.

Most people just rip them off from the web, but I'm looking for an honest source.

A while ago, I found a website marketplace where you could commission stuff from graphic artists.   Does anyone have any links for these?   The sort of thing I mean is like this:  http://www.graphicster.com/Default.aspx  (But those guys haven't got critical mass yet).  Or these guys http://www.crowdspring.com/how-it-works/  (but they seem a bit high end)

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use Open Clip Art ([openclipart.org](http://openclipart.org/)), mostly for free and clear licensing rules.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at these links.

[Glyphish – Great icons for great iPhone applications](http://glyphish.com/)

[35 Free Icon Sets for your iPhone – Pimp it Up!](http://speckyboy.com/2008/07/18/35-free-icon-sets-for-your-iphone-pimp-it-up/)

[iPhone Icons by judge](http://www.iconarchive.com/category/application/iphone-icons-by-judge.html)

[Freebies: 15 Free iPhone Icon Sets](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/freebies-15-free-icon-sets-for-your-iphone/)

If you want to buy some icons, take a look at these links:

[Stock Icons - Royalty-Free Icons for Web & Software](http://www.icondrawer.com/buy.php)

[Facebook, iPhone, Android and Blackberry Icon and Logo Design](http://www.iconiza.com/portfolio.html)

[iPhone Icon Packs | Create iPhone Application Mock-Ups And Presentations](http://www.iphonedesigntools.com/)

This question in a forum may help you:

[Where to buy iPhone icons???](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/off-topic/36956-where-buy-iphone-icons.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can look at 
http://icons.mysitemyway.com/

Loads of icons in different styles.

Answer (score 4):

Map Icons Collection: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/

Comment: link moved to http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try http://dryicons.com/free-icons/ they have free icons sets. some of them are really nice.

Answer (score 1):

look for here. You'll find exactly what you're looking for, there's a very large selection at [Mega Icons](http://megaicons.net/).